# org.json.JSONException how can i clear this using volley library

Tags: json, android-volley

Pls if any one know answer this question.

I have a error of JSONArray can't be converted in to JSONObject..
and I am new to using this volley library

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONArray product = (JSONArray) response
                                        .get(i);
                                String productId = product.getString(Integer.parseInt("productId"));
                                String productName =product.getString(Integer.parseInt("productName"));
                                String productPrice = product.getString(Integer.parseInt("productPrice"));
                                String productImage =product.getString(Integer.parseInt("productImage"));

                                jsonResponse += "productId: " + productId + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "productName: " + productName + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "productPrice: " + productPrice + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "productImage: " + productImage + "\n\n\n";
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is a string and you are trying to assing it to jsonArray